# Tomcat resets session for each request

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm having an interesting problem. I work on a servlet based web project with session usage. When I'm working on my development machine and its local tomcat server, sessions are just fine. Attributes were added in one request, and used in another without any problems. After a while, I deployed the website on a remote machine and session management got broken.

As I observed, tomcat fires sessionCreated event for each request and gives the same id. I'm using chrome's development tool to check headers and browser seems fine sending the session id. Since tomcat renews the session, it loses the attributes.

BTW: application runs under a subdomain such as webproject.example.com

Content of context.xml is pretty basic

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="" sessionCookiePath="/"/>
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: each request and gives the same id - do you mean gives a new id for each request?

Comment: @6ton No. It fires sessionCreated and renews the session with the same session id again.

Comment: Check if you have a http server or a load balancer that intercepts your request and maybe misconfigured

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that cookies are enabled on the client's browser. If they are not, there is no persistent identifier provided by which a session can be retrieved. In this case, `request.getSession()` will create a new session on each request.